# How to Transform a Matrix According to Chunks in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I want a function that takes a integer `n`, and a square matrix of size `(n*n) x (n*n)`, and returns a matrix where each chunk (of size `n x n`) is now a row, ordering chunks by going from left-to-right, then top-to-bottom.

For example:

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]

chunks :: Int -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
chunks n = ...
```

Example : `chunks 2 a == b`

```
   a           b
+--+--+     +--+--+
|ab|cd|     |ab|ef|
|ef|gh|     |cd|gh|
+--+--+ --> +--+--+
|ij|kl|     |ij|mn|
|mn|op|     |kl|op|
+--+--+     +--+--+
```

Example : `chunks 3 c == d`

```
      c                 d
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
|abc|def|ghi|     |abc|jkl|stu|
|jkl|mno|pqr|     |def|mno|vwx|
|stu|vwx|yzA|     |ghi|pqr|yzA|
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
|BCD|EFG|HIJ|     |BCD|KLM|TUV|
|KLM|NOP|QRS| --> |EFG|NOP|WXY|
|TUV|WXY|Z$%|     |HIJ|QRS|Z$%|
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
|...|...|...|     |...|...|...|
|...|...|...|     |...|...|...|
|...|...|...|     |...|...|...|
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
```

*** Edit:

The answer:

```
chunks :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
chunks n m = concat (map chunks' (splitEvery n m))
    where
        chunks' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
        chunks' m = map concat (transpose (map (splitEvery n) m))
```

I suppose I should define `splitEvery` too:

```
splitEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEvery _ [] = []
splitEvery n xs = chunk : (splitEvery n xxs)
    where
        (chunk, xxs) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: It would be important to see what you have tried so far, even if it's in a different programming language, and where your difficulties arise. Is this homework?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out now, thanks to user5402. I hadn't thought of using `transpose`, even though I was already using it elsewhere in the program. No, it's not homework. It's to write a program that solves sudoku puzzles. It's useful to wrap a chunk into a list so I can easily do further operations to it, like turn it into a multiset of candidate values.

Comment: In that case you may like to take a look at this lab http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA555/lab3.html), which guides you through building a sudoku solver in Haskell step by step.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need it. I'm already 99% done, and my algorithm does smarter checks than his before resorting to guessing. My old `chunks` function worked fine, but only for 9x9 puzzles. I just wanted a function that'd work with a puzzle of any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

Note that some elements always stay together. For example, in the 2x2 case `"ab"` stays together, as does `"cd"`, `"ef"`, `"gh"`, etc. In fact, you canvisualize the transformation this way:

```
+---+---+          +---+---+
| 1 | 2 |          | 1 | 3 |        1 = ab
| 3 | 4 |          | 2 | 4 |        2 = cd
+---+---+   --->   +---+---+        3 = ef
| 5 | 6 |          | 5 | 7 |        4 = gh
| 7 | 8 |          | 6 | 8 |        5 = ...
+---+---+          +---+---+
```

And observe how each row gets transformed:

```
1 2   ->   1 3
3 4        2 4

5 6   ->   5 7
7 8        6 8
```

Think about your linear algebra class. Do these transformations
look familiar? Note that the diagonal elements don't move.

Now have a look at this section from the `Data.List` docs, and
see if one of those functions seems applicable:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:2